# ¿Cómo validar rango de horas y minutos donde se encuentra TimeSpan en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo  un  TimeSpan   de nombre **start**  y necesito es determinar en qué rango se encuentra.

Algo así, por ejemplo:

```
TimeSpan start  = 09:10;

if ( start >= 08: 00 && start < 09:00)
{
     Código que se ejecuta
}
else if (start >= 09:00 && start < 10:00)
{
    Código que se ejecuta
 }
```

¿Cómo puedo solventar esto?

Answer (score 3):

Si bien puedes comparar si el valor se encuentra rango, puedes ayudarte creando un  [método extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) para que pueda comprarse un TimeSpan asi lo reutilizas y el código queda mas limpio.

Dejo un ejemplo de un método extensión IsBetween para un objeto TimeSpan.

Ejemplo del método
[Gist > TimeSpanExtensions > IsBetween](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/61f4ded30ffc1edd419f77a7ed887add)

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
     public static bool IsBetween(this TimeSpan target, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
     {
        if (target == start) return true;
        if (target == end) return true;

        if (start <= end)
          return (target >= start && target <= end);
        else
           return !(target >= end && target <= start);
     }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

Lo puedes probar online aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rxkpp3

```
     public static void Main()
    {
       var time0810 = TimeSpan.Parse("08:10");
       var time0800 = TimeSpan.Parse("08:00");
    
       var time0900 = TimeSpan.Parse("09:00");
       var time1000 = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00");
    
       Console.WriteLine(time0810.IsBetween(time0800, time0900));
       Console.WriteLine(time0810.IsBetween(time0900, time1000));
   }
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Métodos de extensión - Guía de programación de C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Answer (score 2):

Es justo como lo pones en tu pregunta, solo te falta parsear los intervalos que se encuentran dentro del condicional:

```
var start = TimeSpan.Parse("08:10");

if( start >= TimeSpan.Parse("08:00") && start < TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"))
{
    // Código que se ejecuta
}
else if (start >= TimeSpan.Parse("09:00") && start < TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"))
{
    // Código que se ejecuta
}
```